# Can LibreOffice Writer display information about the current cursor position?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, statusbar

Preferably in the **status bar** and spelled out in some distance units, but I'd settle for anywhere really. I'm really surprised it doesn't show such crucial information as default.

I want something like this from MS Word 2002:

[image: Cursor position in MS Word status bar]

Comment: It was reported as a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=18004) in 2003 and never fixed :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible yet. You should subscribe and vote for it (up to 2 votes per issue) : [Issue 18004 - Line Number of Cursor Position Should Be Shown in Status Bar.](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=18004)

Comment: Subscribed, voted and commented

Answer (score 1):

You can get an exact cursor position in Writer if you invoke the Draw tool.

To invoke the Draw tool: Menu > View > Toolbars > Drawing

The draw toolbar should appear at the bottom of the Writer window. Select the big white cursor pointer tool on the left. Now when you move the cursor over the page, its horizontal ruler position will be shown on the right-hand side of the toolbar.

***Having said that, the ruler position it gives seems bizarrely unreliable.***

[image]

It's a bit long-winded and clunky. But it works.

There is a suggestion [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=55739), that you might be able to write a macro to do it.